# С# закрытие приложения по закрытию модального окна

Tags: c#, winforms

Здравствуйте. Только недавно стал копаться в С#. Информации вокруг да около моей проблемы много, но в цель ничего не попадает, либо я упускаю что-то. Вот и решил впервые сам что-то спросить. Постараюсь описать проблему подробно, но без лишних вводных.

Используется:
VS 2015, Windows Forms

Описание:
По старту главной формы (Form1) вызывается модальное окно(Form2)

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Form2 ftest = new Form2();
    ftest.ShowDialog();
}
```

Задача:
При закрытии пользователем модального окна (например, нажатием на крестик), полностью закрывается все приложение.

Наверняка есть какой-то естественный способ, прошу подсказать (желательно доходчиво). Пробовал адаптировать под свою задачу различные варианты из сети по сколь-нибудь похожим запросам, но результаты отрицательные: либо ошибки при выполнении, либо игнор (просто закрывается Form2 и открывается главное окно, как будто ничего и не предпринималось). Все испробованные извращенства описать не смогу, т.к. просто их не вспомню уже.

Чисто по логике, у меня напрашиваются два варианта: как-то отлавливается закрытие модального окна и по этому событию происходит закрытие программы, либо, например, при закрытии модального окна, главное окно получает отсутствие результата с диалога и тогда само закрывается...

Не получается, но хочу добить. Как неправильно, как правильно? Как реализовать?

Comment: Мне кажется вы совсем ничего не читали по теме, попробуйте самостоятельно разобраться, у формы множество событий.

Comment: Я понимаю, как это выглядит, и что вопрос откровенно глупый, а я выгляжу дурачком, который даже не погуглил). Читал много чего, но, боюсь, все не то. За какой бы вариант не брался - рабочий вариант не получается. Видимо, придется повспоминать что пробовал. Например, вариант с чьего-то удаленного уже комментария я ранее пробовал через 
            if (ftest.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
                Application.Exit();

Comment: Выглядело логично. Результат - повторное открытие Form2 после его же закрытия, а после повторного закрытия - открытие Form1. Причина для меня не ясна.

Использование в коде Form2 "private void Form2_Closing" просто игнорируется, либо я неправильно как-то это дело использовал.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public Form1()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  Form2 ftest = new Form2();
  if (ftest.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
    Environment.Exit(0);
}
```

Comment: О, подобное пробовал, только через Application.Exit(), что не давало результата. А этот вариант дает казус в виде повторного открытия Form2. Права, если его еще раз закрыть, то программка действительно завершится.
 Но попробовал данный код в пустом проекте - все работает как надо. Значит, проблема в моем проекте (именно в куче неуказанных мной вводных). Уже знаю в какую сторону копать - спасибо!

Comment: @HitoHito, в коде написано `Form2 ftest = new Form2();
  if (ftest.ShowDialog()`, а не `Form2 ftest = new Form2();
  ftest.ShowDialog();
  if (ftest.ShowDialog()`.

Comment: @HitoHito - Вы вызываете `ftest.ShowDialog()` два раза

Comment: А ведь и точно, разумеется! Вот, часто у меня какие-то глупые ошибки появляются, о которых я даже и не подумаю, если спустя сутки мозгового штурма глаза случайно не ткнутся, или кто-то не ткнет носом). Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Можно сделать так:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Form2 ftest = new Form2();
    ftest.ShowDialog();
    this.Close();
}
```

Но вообще-то возникает вопрос, зачем тебе вообще нужна Form1, если она не используется? Просто зайди в свойства проекта и выстави стартовый объект `Form2`. Тогда у тебя сразу будет запускаться вторая форма, а при её закрытии приложение будет завершаться.

Comment: Понял, что моя постановка задачи вызвала разночтение. На самом деле в Form2 происходят некоторые манипуляции, влияющие на дальнейшую работу программы, которая продолжается по нажатию кнопки в Form2 (завершается диалог и продолжается работа главной формы). Я это не стал расписывать, подумав, что это имеет малый вес для конкретной задачи. Виноват :)
Хотя, в любом случае, подобное решение вызывает System.ObjectDisposedException

Comment: @HitoHito, попробуй перенести `Form2 ftest = new Form2();
    ftest.ShowDialog();
    this.Close();` в обработчик `Form_Load` вместо конструктора.

Comment: Уже решил проблему, разобравшись с соседним ответом от Igor, но ради интереса опробовал - да, после переноса такой вариант тоже работает, и в пустом проекте и в контексте моей программы. Спасибо, буду иметь в виду! Надо будет побольше почитать чем технически отличается Load формы от ее инициализации :).